# Accessing Kubernetes dashboard running on a private k8 cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops, nginx-ingress

I have set up a private K8 cluster on AWS using kops with 1 master and 5 nodes. The master and the worker nodes are on a vpc which has `172.20.*.*` subnet.
We have another vpc for dev environment which has instances on the `172.17.*.*` subnet.

There is no way to access the nodes on the 172.20 subnet from the 172.17 instances other than using the bastion host. Now, I have installed the kube-dashboard and configured a service to expose the dashboard so that instances on 172.17 can access it but it's not working.

Script to create the service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

---

```
kubectl describe services kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
Name:                     kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:              kube-system
Labels:     k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal":"0.0.0.0/0"},"label...
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
Selector:                 k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard Type:           LoadBalancer IP:                       100.68.65.76
LoadBalancer Ingress:    
internal-a29aca39505ba11e9b822124a0b1194c-219044523.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31359/TCP
Endpoints:      
100.103.144.50:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy: 
Cluster Events:
Type    Reason                Age   From    Message
----    ------                ----  ----    -------
Normal  Type                  19m   service-controller  ClusterIP -> LoadBalancer   Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  19m   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer   Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   19m   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

When I try to connect to the lb `https://internal-a29aca39505ba11e9b822124a0b1194c-219044523.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443, it times out.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong and how to access the dashboard.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you connect to the service on the same subnet? is it just an issue between different VPCs?

Comment: There is just one vpc and there are different subnets within the vpc. Through the company's vpn we can only access 172.17.. subnet but the cluster is in 172.20.. subnet

Comment: can you access your cluster service within `172.20`?>

Comment: No I cant. But the bastion host is also in 172.20 subnet and I can ssh it using the loadbalancer

Comment: did you consider using `kubectl proxy`?

Comment: the documentation says that the dashboard will be accessible from where you run the kubectl proxy command, when i run it on the master, it starts a service on localhost:8001 but how should i expose it ?